# What is a good strategy to beat the more difficult battles in battle mode?

Tags: achievements, injustice-gods-among-us

I am going for the **[Ultimate Battler](http://www.trueachievements.com/a175636/ultimate-battler-achievement.htm)** achievement in Injustice: Gods Among Us and there are 3 battles that I cannot beat.

1. *Survivor* - Your Heath Meter carries over from match to match! Perform feats of exceptional skill to obtain bonus health.
2. *The Max* -  You have one chance to defeat all of your opponents at maximum difficulty!
3. *Impossible!* - Attempt to defeat the entire cast of Injustice with a single Health Meter!

The main problem I have with *Survivor* and *Impossible!* is health management. About 3/4's of the way through both of these battles I violently struggle to maintain my health levels. I know that neither of these fights have a 'Very Hard' difficulty fight but I struggle with health management when the fights start to converge on the harder difficulties.

As for *The Max*, I cannot even beat one fight. No matter what I throw at the CPU, they always perfectly block and or counter/punish me. I cannot find an opening or a strategy to defeat even one enemy, let alone 10.

Comment: practice, practice, practice. I don't think there are any shortcuts or anything we can do to help you. It's just your own skill.

Comment: Unfortunately Novarg is correct. [Doomsday](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/672472-injustice-gods-among-us/66149586) and [Hawkgirl](http://www.trueachievements.com/a175636/ultimate-battler-achievement.htm) spam are common approaches, but still require sufficient skill and luck to execute successfully. All you can really do is practice.

Comment: I am more looking for retrospective advice from someone who has completed the achievement than a list of steps to follow. I am very familiar with the game as well as both the Doomsday and Hawkgirl methods, but I cannot get either to work post-patch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Some comments found around the net pertaining to the matches, doesn't looks like there are guaranteed strategies, just tactics that should be employed:**

For Impossible, remember that you get a health percentage bonus depending on what you do during your fights. You always get at least a 25% health bonus too. Here are some requirements:

Performing a 30% Combo
Winning a Clash
Using an Interactive Object

As well as other factors. You can get a 45-50% health bonus from those above. Try performing these every fight to keep your health as high as possible. Obviously you'll want to use the Doomsday method mentioned above and beware of characters that give him the most trouble such as The Flash, Green Lantern, Lex, and Superman. If the CPU isn't falling for your combo be sure to pause and attack them when you see an opening, usually crouching heavy attack up close. Usually you lose track of health toward the middle but if you have a few good matches with safe pausing techniques you an slowly earn it back. It's all about being careful really. And use your Super Meter wisely, it carries over like your health. Use it to win clashes, Super Moves are not necessary unless you're losing badly.

---

I also used Doomsday pre-patch for The Max and jumping down+A, X X Y is all you need together with the Meter Burn version of down, back + Y. The A.I. won't block or dodge this pre-patch 90 percent of the time so make sure to use it. The block damage of the last Y attack is just insane and wil add up over time.

The only things that bothered me were the characters I got. As long as I got Green Arrow, Green Lantern, Lex Luthor and Aquaman, I restarted. Batman kicked my butt at stage 10 two times due to his counter move, so make sure that he isn't one of the last in the roster.

Other than that the A.I. really isn't clever. I abused respawning interactibles like mad when I had the chance. As long as you walk slowly backbard the A.I. will follow you and walk into the interactibles most of the time. Patience and luck is all you need here. Took me around 6-7 hours for The Max alone while I beat Impossible on my first try.

---

How on earth are you supposed to beat the AI on max difficulty without trying? I can barely do that WITH retrying. The AI constantly reads your inputs and reacts so it's extremely hard. Anyone got any tips?

-DD supernova spam and armor. Deathstroke gun spam. Superman air heat vision spam. Also, abuse dat meter.

-Try command grab characters.

---